# running chkdsk on SD card throws "Cannot open volume for direct access" error

Tags: windows, data-recovery, sd-card, chkdsk

Please consider that I am running `chkdsk` on the SD card, not my boot drive. Therefore solutions mentioned in other posts including "clean boot" or "safe mode" don't apply to my case.

I'm running the commands

```
chkdsk /X /f D:
```

and

```
chkdsk D: /f
```

commands, however as said in the title it throws the

> Cannot open volume for direct access.

error message. I have tried restarting and placing the SD card back (even with an external SD card reader), without avail. I know the drive exists because running the command:

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption
```

I can see

```
Caption
C:
D:
```

Where `C:` is my boot drive and `D:` disappears when I unplug the SD card reader.

I don't want to format the SD card, hoping I can recover the data. I don't want to install any third-party software. I prefer to use cmd or PowerShell to solve my problem.

Comment: Couple of points: 1. You are aware that chkdsk doesn't give a damn about your data, yes? Its job is to fix the filesystem, which it will do at cost to any data it has to discard to do that task. 2. The card's probably dead, but if you want to try scavenging for any surviving data, start with something like photorec or testdisk, not chkdsk.

Comment: … and a late 3. **Never, ever** entrust the only copy of any data to something as unreliable as a USB stick or SD card. That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: https://silicophilic.com/cannot-open-volume-for-direct-access-error/